# Azure AD B2C Create Tenant

Tags: azure, automation, ansible, azure-ad-b2c

I want to automate creation of AD B2C Create Tenant and linked to my existing AD. So I'm asking if there's a CLI or ansible playbook can automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid currently there is no way to automate this. [Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18960694-deploy-and-manage-active-directory-b2c-using-arm-t) is a feedback regarding the same topic posted by others. You can vote it up. Azure AD Team will evaluate whether this feature is added.